# Getting weird bugs when trying to update to Kotlin 1.4.0. How to make it work with Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Kotlin 1.4.0 is stable now. Therefor, I wanted to update my multi module Android project to use it. I set IDEA to use Kotlin plugin 1.4.0-release-IJ2020.2-1 and in my buildSrc build.gradle.kts using Kotlin DSL, I'm loading Kotlin for the jvm like this:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.0"
}
```

My app level plugins block looks like this

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}
```

I have also added the Kotlin stdlib to my app level build.gradle.kts dependencies

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.0")
```

When trying to build my project now, I get multiple Errors like the following:

```
'let((T) -> R): R' is only available since Kotlin 1.3.50 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.3
```

I don't understand. How is gradle trying to use Kotlin 1.3 here? Any idea on how to fix this? Its working fine when using Kotlin v1.3.72 instead.

What I tried so far:

- Clean Project
- Invalidate caches and restart
- Delete .gradle folder and restart
- Fix broken classes paths

**UPDATE**
Forgot to mention that I'm also getting the following warning. How is it unsupported when it is stable?

```
> Configure project :buildSrc
WARNING: Unsupported Kotlin plugin version.
The `embedded-kotlin` and `kotlin-dsl` plugins rely on features of Kotlin `1.3.72` that might work differently than in the requested version `1.4.0`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should add the Kotlin standard lib to your dependencies explicitly?

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}
```

With Kotlin 1.4 it is no longer required it add this dependency. The plugin applies the Stdlib by default to the projects it is applied to.

From the [Kotlin 1.4 release notes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library-added-by-default):

> You no longer need to declare a dependency on the stdlib library in any Kotlin Gradle project, including a multiplatform one. The dependency is added by default.
>
> The automatically added standard library will be the same version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin, since they have the same versioning.

Comment: I have done that. See edited question. BTW, compile is deprecated.

Comment: ok, I have replaced my  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.0") with  your version: implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
I don't understand why but now it works!

Comment: That's really strange, but the original error was as well. ;)
Glad it helped in the end! :)

Comment: Just remembered that the Kotlin 1.4 release notes mentioned that you no longer need to add a dependency on Kotlin Std Lib to the project:  

"You no longer need to declare a dependency on the stdlib library in any Kotlin Gradle project, including a multiplatform one. The dependency is added by default.
The automatically added standard library will be the same version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin, since they have the same versioning."  

This makes your issue even stranger. Maybe there is a dependency resolution rule in your project or any plugin that forces Kotlin to version 1.3.x?

Comment: Link to section in release notes: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library-added-by-default

Comment: Thanks for the update on this. It seems my issue was due to a different mistake then, because it makes no sense otherwise. The gradle build indeed works without stdlib provided. You could update your answer with the additional info. edit: I'm still getting the "WARNING: Unsupported Kotlin plugin version.", though.